# Hide thumbnail on search results when thumbnail not set - using Oxygen

Tags: functions, thumbnails

I am using Oxygen to build a search results page. I am very new to CSS and PHP editing. I just floated an image right for the first time. So please forgive my ignorance.

I want to stop the thumbnail placeholder appearing in the search results when the post does not have a thumbnail/feature image set. I know that function that gets the image is `<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>` but I have no clue how I would write the code to say if the post thumbnail is false (? maybe) then don't display the thumbnail.

Is anyone available to help me? I would be most appreciative.

I've copied the code I am using below and here's a screenshot of the Oxygen editor.

[image]

I am using this code in the Oxygen Template editor.

```
<div class='oxy-post'>
  
    <a class='oxy-post-image' href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'>
      <div class='oxy-post-image-fixed-ratio' style='background-image: url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>);'>
      </div>
      <!--
      <div class='oxy-post-image-date-overlay'>
        <?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?> <?php the_title(); ?> 

      </div>
-->
      
    </a>
  
    <a class='oxy-post-title' href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    <div class='oxy-post-meta'>
<!--
        <div class='oxy-post-meta-author oxy-post-meta-item'>
            <?php the_author(); ?>
        </div>

-->
<!--
        <div class='oxy-post-meta-comments oxy-post-meta-item'>
            <a href='<?php comments_link(); ?>'><?php comments_number(); ?></a>
        </div>
-->
    </div>

    <div class='oxy-post-content'>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
<!--
    <a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' class='oxy-read-more'>Read More</a>
-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> This below if statement checks to see if there is a thumbnail in the post. If not, nothing will display.

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {     
    echo '<div class="oxy-post-image-fixed-ratio" style="background-image: url('.get_the_post_thumbnail_url().')"></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Tanmay - I tried that but I get a server error. I am a complete newbie so do I just copy your code in place of the current php tag?


I tried that and got a server error.

Comment: @PatBirgan I have updated above code. so please try it again.

Comment: Here's a screenshot.  https://imgur.com/waMw7vK

Now the thumbnail names is overlaid on top of the thumbnail but the thumbnail still appears when none are set

Comment: you have wrote 2 times same divs one I have wrote in my code and one you have already written in your code so just replace this your code <div class='oxy-post-image-fixed-ratio' style='background-image: url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>);'>
      </div> to my updated above code

Comment: @PatBirgan you can replace this red marker code https://prnt.sc/10pmcln to my above updated code.

Comment: OK @tanmay-patel I have done that but same result. 

https://imgur.com/vjgfpeK